# How to start and stop a web application and database in VSO with vNext tasks

Tags: azure-devops

I've setup `Continuous Integration` in my project hosted at `Visual Studio Online`.

Among other things, I deploy my web application to a test slot and test database and I run integration tests.

However, I don't need the test slot and database to be running all the time. I would like to start them both for the integration tests to run and stop them after my integration tests are done, all automated.

I played around with the Azure PowerShell vNext task, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated. More than the actual answer, I would appreciate a link with more information, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the web app slot, you can add AzurePowerShell step in your build defition can create two power-shell script: one start the website via [Start-AzureWebsite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495288.aspx) command before the build start and another one stop the website via [Stop-AzureWebsite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495185.aspx) after the testing is finished.

For the database, you cannot stop it. Refer to this question for details: [How do I stop and start a SQL Azure database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262001/how-do-i-stop-and-start-a-sql-azure-database)