# how to restart Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database

1. please help me to restart my Azure SQL database in Azure portal
2. my tempdb is full and how clear my tempdb
3. [List item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IAxI.png)

Comment: Please contact Microsoft support if your tempdb is in a state where it is full all of the time.  Generally you would want to avoid long-lived tables in tempdb in PaaS if possible.

Comment: any other way to restart Azure SQL database

Answer (score 0):

We cannot stop/start the SQL Azure servers. A SQL Azure Database resides on a shared host.
But I think we can reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108537/13979487), as the answer mentioned, **Scale the database to another tier and then scale it back!**